# Sentence string to word array javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a way to convert an input string "javascriptisalovelylanguage" into and array ['javascript', 'is','a','lovely','language'].

Comment: `substring()`.......................

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post some code. Are you able to separate the words with a special character?

Comment: You kind of have to define what words to look for and then split the word accordingly.  There's really no easy way to determine whether or not a series of characters is a word without an entire dictionary to reference.

How would you distinguish javascript from java script?

Unless you're only talking about this one specific instance, then use `yourString.substring()`.  More here:  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp